# Why doesn't backspace navigation request for get/post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using Node and Express, I check the session to see if a user is logged in, so that if the browser reaches the login page and a session is in place, it redirects to the profile page. However, after logging in, if I press backspace, I am allowed to be on the login page. Then, if I refresh, I get redirected to the profile page. How come this happens, and what can I do to change this? Is this an issue regardless of the framework? Thank you.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (session.verified) {
        res.redirect(path);
    }
    else {
        res.render('login.html');
    }
});
```

Comment: share some code and a [mcve]

Comment: When you press backspace the page isnt reloaded, so the servercode isnt executed. May check for a cookie in javascript when the site is reloaded...

Comment: @DanielA.White I put a sample code in there now. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, that's what I thought was happening. Is there a way to make it reload?

Comment: login -> login ( display "loading..." +redirect) -> page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting, you could respond with a
Redirect.html:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/mainpage" />
</head>
<body>
Redirecting...
(If you see that to long, please notify the admin)
</body>
```

If you watch the urls at famous sites you see a simillar behaviour. Theyve got a page that always redirects to another site, so you cannot go back

```
login -> redirect -> page
                     <--- does work but
                      ---> youre redirected again...
```